# connecting 2 simple point layers in neo4j spatial

Tags: neo4j, spatial

How do we connect 2 point layers in neo4j? I don't want all of my points to be located in just a one simple point layer.

Let's say we have 2 point layers,

```
Layer 1 - road network A (upper NY)
Layer 2 - road network B (lower NY)
```

So in neo4j spatial, these 2 are separated layers, each have their own r tree index, etc. So, how do we have a relationship between these 2 layers?

Comment: [ http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask ], [ http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve ]

Comment: edited the question to make it clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by 'connecting 2 point layers'? What kind of connection? If you, for example, add the same point to two layers, then those two layers are connected (by that point). Your second sentence seems to imply the opposite with some points in one layer and some in another. Just add some to one and add others to the other. Perhaps if you tell us more about your actual case, we can advise better.

Comment: Hi Craig, you answered my question, thanks.. now i know we can just add the same node to both layers, and now, those layers are essentially connected through that node